# error when I try handel event from form to another

Tags: c#

what is cause of error;

```
{
    private Form2 testc;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button4.Visible = true;
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }

    public void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2_Click(this, null);
        testc = new Form2() ;
        testc.Show();
    }
}
```

I want active on button has picture box from form 1 using form 2 that all i need , but i face off problem .

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.pictureBox2_Click(object, EventArgs)'  WindowsFormsApplication7

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 private Form1 test;
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.pictureBox2_Click(this, null);
    }
}
```

IF I change a code like this , in Main Project(not for testing)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
        test = new MainForm();
        test.Refill_sy_Click(this, null);
        test.Show();
```

give this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6ClS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form1` is a *type*, not a *variable*.  Your variable is called `test`:

```
private Form1 test;
```

In order to *use* that variable, you'd need to initialize it to something.  For example:

```
test = new Form1();
```

Then you can use it:

```
test.pictureBox2_Click(this, null);
```

Though it's *highly unusual* to directly invoke an event handler like this, and probably an indication of a problem in the design.  It's more likely that you want to abstract the logic in that handler to its own method.  Then both of these handlers would call that method.

It's also of course worth noting that you'll need to *show* your instance of `Form1` in order to see whatever it's doing on its interface.

Comment: private MainForm test;
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {
            test = new MainForm();
            test.Refill_sy_Click(this, null);
            test.Show();} it give me object refernce  not set an instance of an object.@David

Comment: @KokakoKokako: For that you’d need to find what’s null and where it’s being referenced.  The exception stack trace will help with that.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: thank you for helping , I found the solution and write it below, thank you again .

Answer (score 1):

I found this way is the best way to handler ; button in form to another do the same funcation

```
var y = Application.OpenForms["MainForm"] as MainForm;
            y.Refill_sy_Click(this, null);
```